# Generate UUID once app finishes installation for Android studio

Tags: android

I'm developing android app and i want the user to get unique random id once he finishes installing the app and it will be displayed in text label, and the UUID wouldn't change even if the user closes the app it will still be the same, can you please help me with that? thanks in advance. (I'm working with android studio)

Comment: **i couldn't find the code**? you won't be able to. Write something.

Comment: Yah i tried but i couldn't write it so i was wondering if any did that code and could paste it here, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i was wondering if any did that code and could paste it here

Lazy boy... ^^

To do what you want, you need to know that you can't generate anything when app is just installed. But you can do the trick on first launch.

**How to detect "first launch"**

You will to read/write `SharedPreferences`. In `Application.onCreate()`, you will check if a defined key is present in the `SharedPreferences`, let say "uuid_key". If it is present, you know that it is not the first launch and if not, it is the first launch (well..the first launch after app data have been erased)

**How to read SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sharedPref.getString("uuid_key", "");
if (TextUtils.isNullOrEmpty()) {
  // it is the first launch !
  // let's generate UUID !
}
```

**How to generate UUID**

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

You now just have to save it inside the `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("uuid_key", uuid);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks and I'm not lazy xD I'm still new with android studio and thank you so much! i will try it now

Comment: According to your context, `context` must be replaced by `this`. And use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`